# Adding a skeleton loader/typing indicator using turbo

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm currently in the process of trying to add a typing indicator for a chat feature I implemented dealing with GPT-4. What I have is the following create action

```rb
# controllers/lessons/sections/messages_controller.rb

def create
  @chat = Chat.find_or_create_by(section_id: @section.id, user_id: current_user.id)      
  @message = @chat.messages.build(content: message_params[:content], sender: 'user')
  if @message.save
    respond_to do |format|
        format.turbo_stream { render turbo_stream: turbo_stream.append("messages", partial: "lessons/sections/messages/message", locals: { message: @message }) }            
    end
    CompletionJob.perform_later(@chat, @message)
  else
    @messages = @chat.messages.order(created_at: :asc)
    @new_message = Message.new
    render "sections/show"
  end
end
```

and the CompletionJob is as follows

```rb
class CompletionJob < ApplicationJob
  queue_as :default

  def perform(chat, message)
    client = OpenAI::Client.new(access_token: Rails.application.credentials[Rails.env.to_sym][:openai][:api_key])
    response = client.chat(
        parameters: {
            model: "gpt-4", 
            messages: [{role: "system", content: "lorem ipsum" },
                       { role: "user", content: message.content}],
            temperature: 0.7,
        })
    completion = chat.messages.create(content: response.dig("choices", 0, "message", "content"), sender: 'assistant')
    Turbo::StreamsChannel.broadcast_append_to(chat, target: "messages", partial: "lessons/sections/messages/message", locals: { message: completion })
  end
end
```

and the relevant part of the view

```html
<%= turbo_stream_from @chat %>
<div data-controller="chat" class="fixed inset-x-4 bottom-4 md:inset-x-8 md:bottom-8 md:left-auto flex flex-col items-end">
    <div data-chat-target="widget" class="hidden mb-2 max-w-xl w-full">
        <div class="shadow-2xl rounded-md mb-4">
            <div class="bg-blue-950 px-4 md:px-6 py-5 rounded-t-md relative">
                <h2 class="text-xl text-white font-semibold mb-2">Bot</h2>
                <p class="text-white">Hi I'm a bot.</p>
                <button data-action="chat#toggle" type="button" class="absolute text-white top-3 right-3">
                    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" class="h-6 w-6" fill="none" viewBox="0 0 24 24" stroke="currentColor"><path stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-width="2" d="M6 18L18 6M6 6l12 12"></path></svg>
                </button>
            </div>
            <div class="px-4 md:px-6 py-5 bg-white rounded-b-md">
                <div data-chat-target="container" class="h-52 overflow-y-auto mb-4 border-t border-gray-200 pt-4">
                    <%= turbo_frame_tag "messages" do %>       
                        <%= render partial: 'lessons/sections/messages/message', collection: @messages, cached: true %>
                    <% end %>
                    <div data-chat-target="loader" class="hidden">
                        <div class="ticontainer">
                        <div class="tiblock">
                            <div class="tidot"></div>
                            <div class="tidot"></div>
                            <div class="tidot"></div>
                        </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <%= render 'lessons/sections/messages/form', message: @new_message %>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
    <button data-action="chat#toggle" type="button" class="flex items-center bg-blue-950 hover:bg-blue-1000 text-white p-2 rounded-md">
        <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" fill="none" viewBox="0 0 24 24" stroke-width="1.5" stroke="currentColor" class="w-7 h-7 block">
            <path stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" d="M7.5 8.25h9m-9 3H12m-9.75 1.51c0 1.6 1.123 2.994 2.707 3.227 1.129.166 2.27.293 3.423.379.35.026.67.21.865.501L12 21l2.755-4.133a1.14 1.14 0 01.865-.501 48.172 48.172 0 003.423-.379c1.584-.233 2.707-1.626 2.707-3.228V6.741c0-1.602-1.123-2.995-2.707-3.228A48.394 48.394 0 0012 3c-2.392 0-4.744.175-7.043.513C3.373 3.746 2.25 5.14 2.25 6.741v6.018z" />
        </svg>
    </button>
</div>
```

as well as the stimulus controller

```js
import { Controller } from "@hotwired/stimulus";

export default class extends Controller {
    static targets = ["widget", "container", "form", "loader"];

    connect() {
        const messages = this.containerTarget;
        messages.addEventListener('DOMNodeInserted', () => {
            messages.scrollTop = messages.scrollHeight;
        });
    }

    toggle() {
        this.widgetTarget.classList.toggle("hidden");
    }

    showLoader() {
        this.loaderTarget.classList.remove("hidden");
    }

    hideLoader() {
        this.loaderTarget.classList.add("hidden");
    }

    resetForm() {
        this.formTarget.reset();
    }
}
```

I'm slightly confused about how to use turbo now to show the loader on the page for as long as the CompletionJob has finished. Is there some neat way to do this?